# No name 'path' issue, unable to start project in django, lubuntu

Tags: python, django, path, pip

So I recently downloaded python3 and django-2 but I realised my computer has already python 2 and django 1.11, so I managed to create project with django 3 using python3 django -m startproject or something like this, even I managed to create a django 2 project, this time at the urls.py, it says "No name 'path' in module 'django.urls'.

Can you help me with how to create a project using django2 and python3 in lubuntu and this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first install the django by `sudo python3 -m pip install django` after that check for the version by `python3 -m django --version` it will surely be the latest version of the django and then start your project by `django-admin startproject mysite` where `mysite` is the name of project you want to start. This problem may be arised due to an old version of django, so you have to use the latest version of django.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Okay it's all great, I managed to create a project and run it on the server, what I got as a problem is the pylint in visual studio code marks underneath the 'from' keyword at 'from django.urls import path' and says no name path in module bla bla but it works perfectly, how can I make that red mark go away?

Comment: if your code is working fine without giving any error regarding missing package or anything. Then, it's fine. Maybe VSC is not able to read the packages and hence gives the red line below the text. But still, I am not sure what can be the exact case.